# Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements

Tags: tokenize

`I have a problem while tokenizing a text.
So here's the following syntax:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# Load the CSV data and handle missing values
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/ASUS/preprocessed_comments.csv", error_bad_lines=False, header=None)

# Set the column name for the dataframe
data.columns = ['comments']

# Remove duplicate rows based on the 'comments' column
data.drop_duplicates(subset=['comments'], keep='first', inplace=True)

# Tokenize 'comments' column directly
tokenized_comments = []
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    try:
        tokens = word_tokenize(row['comments'])`your text`
        tokenized_comments.append(tokens)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error at index {idx}: {e}")
        tokenized_comments.append([])  # Append an empty list for cases where tokenization fails

# Add tokenized comments to the DataFrame
data['tokenized_comments'] = tokenized_comments

# Save to CSV
data.to_csv('tokenized_comments.csv', index=False)
```

And then appeared this kind of error:
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements

How to fix this thing?

I tried to tokenize the text. I expected the comments in the csv file to be tokenized (for example: [I], [have], [a], [weapon])
Resulted in a length mismatch Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements`